# How can i see name of signal received from child?

Tags: c, unix, signals

For example:

```
if (WIFEXITED(status)) {
              printf("Im child, finish with status=%d\n", WEXITSTATUS(status));
```

Is it possible to have name of signal instead of number?

Answer (score 0):

FYI

> ```
> WIFEXITED(status)
> Description:
>  Returns True if status was returned for a child that terminated normally. In this case, we can
>  execute WEXITSTATUS(status) to fetch the value that the child passed to exit, _exit,or _Exit.
> ```

Comment: thanks for info, child can passe various values to exit, i just wanted to know if there is a way to print name of signal, like SIGINT, SIGUSR1

Comment: Yes. You can do that also, but for that you have to modify signal table and add your own ISR.